# Why i am getting Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required init_autoloader.php with zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using ubuntu 15.10 and i have install **zend 3** I am new to zend framework so i have started it with its Skeleton Application tutorial after setting everything from zend official tutorial i am getting this error :-

```
Warning: require(init_autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/zendapp/public/index.php on line 25

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'init_autoloader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/zendapp/public/index.php on line 25
```

My index.php code:-

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 /**
  * Display all errors when APPLICATION_ENV is development.
  */
 if ($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] == 'development') {
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 }

 /**
  * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
  * to the application root now.
  */
 chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

 // Decline static file requests back to the PHP built-in webserver
 if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server' && is_file(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))) {
     return false;
 }

 // Setup autoloading
 require 'init_autoloader.php';

 // Run the application!
 Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Please help me in resolving this issue or tell me if any php modules i need to install thanks.

**Update** :-
After lots of research my add,delete functions and view files are working but when i click on edit link of Albums I am getting an error :-

```
Zend\Stdlib\Exception\BadMethodCallException

File:

    /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/ArraySerializable.php:29

Message:

    Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable::extract expects the provided object to implement getArrayCopy()

Stack trace:

    #0 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Fieldset.php(590): Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable->extract(Object(Album\Model\Album))
    #1 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Form.php(881): Zend\Form\Fieldset->extract()
    #2 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Form.php(303): Zend\Form\Form->extract()
    #3 /var/www/html/zendapp/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php(75): Zend\Form\Form->bind(Object(Album\Model\Album))
    #4 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Album\Controller\AlbumController->editAction()
    #5 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #6 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #7 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #8 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #9 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
    #10 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #11 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #12 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #13 /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #14 /var/www/html/zendapp/public/index.php(26): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
    #15 {main}
```

**Code Files**

- edit Action :-

  ```
  public function editAction()
   {
       $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
       if (!$id) {
           return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
               'action' => 'add'
           ));
       }

       // Get the Album with the specified id.  An exception is thrown
       // if it cannot be found, in which case go to the index page.
       try {
           $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);
       }
       catch (\Exception $ex) {
           return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array(
               'action' => 'index'
           ));
       }

       $form  = new AlbumForm();
       $form->bind($album);
       $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

       $request = $this->getRequest();
       if ($request->isPost()) {
           $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
           $form->setData($request->getPost());

           if ($form->isValid()) {
               $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);

               // Redirect to list of albums
               return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
           }
       }

       return array(
           'id' => $id,
           'form' => $form,
       );
   }
  ```

**2.)**
edit.phtml

```
<?php
 // module/Album/view/album/album/edit.phtml:

 $title = 'Edit album';
 $this->headTitle($title);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>

 <?php
 $form = $this->form;
 $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
     'album',
     array(
         'action' => 'edit',
         'id'     => $this->id,
     )
 ));
 $form->prepare();

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
 echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Comment: you init_autoloader.php is missing. Just try to find the file from zend site.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan after adding this file https://github.com/akrabat/zf2-tutorial/blob/master/init_autoloader.php from here in public folder its showing zend's default welcome page. but i am not able to access album controller getting 404 error when writing http://localhost/zendapp/public/album

Comment: Can you please share your route file's code?

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan if you have zend crud example code then please share it with me. I don't thing anyone can resolve this issue.